Swift program with SceneKit throws error saying that the scene is not declaring an output file
When trying to build my app, I get this error:
shell script build rule for '/Users/user/Desktop/Roomscanner/Roomscanner/RoomModel/RoomPlan Scene.scn' must declare at least one output file
To be quite honest, I am stumped, so I don't know what to try to fix it. I found this question that seemed similar: Xcode 10 build error: 'must declare at least one output file', but I can't find the section that he talks about in the version of Xcode that I have.
The .scn file has a camera inside, and it's being declared as the scene in a different view file, so it should be providing an output. It is my first time working with SceneKit, so there might be some setup that I am supposed to do that I am unaware of.

The issue was a null script being created in the build rules of the .xcodeproj file. By removing that the issue went away.
